# Sidewaystable left align instead of centering

Tags: sidewaystable

I have a sideways table that does not fill the whole page. It is centered, but I want it to be left aligned (or if you turn the book around, to the top). Is there a way to do that? Please find below an example.

```
\documentclass[DIV12, a4paper, 12pt, listof=totocnumbered, bibliography=totoc]{book}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs, tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
    \caption{Overview of the literature}
  \label{tab2:overviewliterature}
  \begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXlXX}

\toprule
Year & Author(s) & Method & (+) & (--) \\
\midrule

xx & xx & xx & xx   \\
\addlinespace


    \bottomrule

  \end{tabularx}
  \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
  \footnotesize
  \item\hspace{-2.5pt}\noindent\textit{Continued on the next page.}  
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}

\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The good news is that you can control the positioning using `\rotFPtop` and `\rotFPbot`.  The bad news is that sideways table sets the height depth and width of `\rot@float@box` to zero, making it impossible to align the edges.  The information icannot be recovered.  OTOH, it is pretty easy to replace sideways table using \rotatebox and a normal table.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `\rotatebox` (adjustbox package) to implement sideways tables.  It uses a minpage covering the text area.  The alignment is handled by the third optional argument: [t] [b] [c] and [s] for stretch (user supplied glue).

```
\documentclass[DIV12, a4paper, 12pt, listof=totocnumbered, bibliography=totoc]{book}
%\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p]
\rotatebox{90}{\begin{minipage}[b][\textwidth][t]{\textheight}
  \caption{Overview of the literature}
  \label{tab2:overviewliterature}
  \begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXlXX}

\toprule
Year & Author(s) & Method & (+) & (--) \\
\midrule

xx & xx & xx & xx   \\
\addlinespace


    \bottomrule

  \end{tabularx}
  \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
  \footnotesize
  \item\hspace{-2.5pt}\noindent\textit{Continued on the next page.}  
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{minipage}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks, the only problem is that the table caption hasnt been rotated. Any idea how to fix this? I cant upload images here so i answered my question to show how it looks like

Answer (score 1):

- instead of `sidewaystable` see if the use of the `pdflandscape` (or if you prefer `lscape` package) and `afterpage` packages gives desired result:

```
\documentclass[DIV12, a4paper, 12pt, listof=totocnumbered, bibliography=totoc]{book}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, tabularx}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text, not needed in real document

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\afterpage{
\begin{landscape}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Overview of the literature}
    \label{tab2:overviewliterature}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXlXX}
    \toprule
Year    & Author(s) & Method    & $(+)$         & $(-)$         \\
    \midrule
xx      & xx        & xx        & \lipsum[66]   & \lipsum[11]   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]\footnotesize
\textit{Continued on the next page.}
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\vfill\mbox{}
\end{landscape}
}

\lipsum[2-9]
\end{document}
```

[image]

- it is not clear, why you use `threeparttable` and `tablenotes` with note that table is continued on the next page?
- If this is case, than the use of `tabularx` will not enable to write to write table over few pages. Instead it you should use for example `xltabular` table environment and use `threeparttable` only if you need table notes.